# VBA command export XML fine but do not replace

Tags: xml, excel, vba, export-to-xml

I'm decided to try my way around VBA, got a little script running to export a XML map I have in a worksheet to XML, works fine so far, but when that XML file is already generated, it returns a error instead of replace it... I tried many ways I've seen in other topics of this forum and around web but because I don't know VBA protocols it's taking me (a lot) of time, can anyone help?

What I have so far:

```
    Sub Export_Main_XML()

Dim JobNumber As String
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("A4").Text
XMLName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & JobNumber & "_Main_Export.xml"
    ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Main_XML_Map").Export URL:=XMLName
End Sub
```

Ideally what I'm looking for is:

Export

-if not file existent, just export (script above)

-if file on same path and name exists > ask to replace "yes or no"

-if yes, replace

-if no, exit

Help please, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look for an existing file, ask to overwrite if it exists - if that's the choice pass `true` to `.Export` to indicate your intention to replace it:

```
JobNumber = Sheet12.Range("A4").Text
XMLName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & JobNumber & "_Main_Export.xml"

'' does it exist already?
If Dir$(XMLName) <> "" Then
    '' exists
    If MsgBox("Overwrite " & XMLName & " ?", vbYesNo, "Confirm Overwrite") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
End If

'' pass true to overwrite
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Main_XML_Map").Export XMLName, True
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Alex, I've been trying it for the last 5 hours.